# Bidirectional LSTM for Classification

Tags: classification, pybrain, bidirectional, lstm

I am done with searching "how to implement bidirectional lstm network for a classification problem (say with iris data)". I have not found any satisfying answer. In almost every cases I came by a solution where BLSTM is implemented for a sequence prediction problem. My simple question is that, how can I create a bidirectional network in **pybrain**. As whenever I am trying to build one I am writing *

> network=pybrain.BidirectionalNetwork()

*
My intention was to add modules later by pybrain.addInputModule() or so. But it is failing of course as I am not specifying seqlen as in

```
n = BidirectionalNetwork(seqlen=20, inputsize=1, 
                         hiddensize=5, symmetric=False)
```

what will be seqlen if I have 4 inputs and 3 outputs(as in iris data) and 150 sample data. will it be 150? Things are not clear as I have no example of classification problem.